# Operating backwords?

Tags: string, visual-c++

In this code you will see it asks for a password. Please note that there is no real password system setup. I am new to c++ and I literally just learned about strings. I understand them but I am not getting good results. It is operating backwords? I do not understand string completely so I do not understand what is happening. I tried googling it but I couldn't find anything.

When I flip username with password it works just fine. So why is it running backwords?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>




std::string password()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter your password. : ";
    std::string password;
    std::getline(std::cin, password);
    return password;
}

std::string username()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter your username. : ";
        std::string username;
        std::getline(std::cin, username);
        return username;
}
int main()
{

    std::cout << "Welcome to the test login! Please enter your username and password to enter. \n \n \n";
    std::cout << username() << password() << "\n \n \n";



    int noEnd{ 0 };
    std::cin >> noEnd;
    return 0;
}
```

Notice if I swap password with username it works.

```
    std::cout << "Welcome to the test login! Please enter your username and password to enter. \n \n \n";
    std::cout << password() << username() << "\n \n \n";
```

But this does not make sense to me. I am knew to c++ and just learned the basics of strings. Theoretically if I have the code like,

```
    std::cout << "Welcome to the test login! Please enter your username and password to enter. \n \n \n";
    std::cout << username() << password() << "\n \n \n";
```

username() should go first but, password() does instead?

Sorry I am knew please don't use like weird functions and things because I will probably not understand them . . . Yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compiler is evaluating `std::cout << password() << username() << "\n \n \n"` from right to left.

According to [ccpreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

> Order of evaluation of the operands of almost all C++ operators
>   (including the order of evaluation of function arguments in a
>   function-call expression and the order of evaluation of the
>   subexpressions within any expression) is unspecified. The compiler can
>   evaluate operands in any order, and may choose another order when the
>   same expression is evaluated again.

The best option is to write code in a way that does not depend on the order it is evaluated.

```
std::string u = username();
std::string p = password();

std::cout << u << p << "\n \n \n";
```